# Datetime colum to float type conversion is getting issue in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'd like alter a column type from `Datetime` to `float`. Hence, I executed the below query but it was getting a issue

```
alter table dbo.purchasedate
alter column supp_dt float null

Error :: Implicit conversion from data type datetime to float is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Comment: What scheme do you want to use for converting to float? The same as an explicit cast where `0` = `1900-01-01`? And why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: I've populate this data from excel, few of them are converted as a datetime column. so i'd like to convert on this format

Comment: What data does the column actually contain? Is it actually numeric but incorrectly formatted as a datetime column in Excel? If so I don't think it will roundtrip correctly except if you manually adjust it by 2. e.g. `NOW()` in Excel is numeric = `41430.64` but `select CAST(41430.64  as datetime)` returns `2013-06-07 15:21:35.997` which is wrong by 2 days.

Comment: If I use try_convert(float, My_Column_Name) it's selecting NULLs for all values. Is there any way to mitigate this and get Non-NULL values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your desired output, you could just: Add Float column, populate, drop date column.

To my knowledge you cannot add a CONVERT to an ALTER statement, anyone know otherwise?

Comment: Populating with an explicit `update table set F = convert(float, datetime_field)`